# Doctrine Entity increase value (Download counter)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I want to increase a value in my doctrine entity.
Currently I'm doing it this way.

```
$file->setDownloadCounter($file->getDownloadCounter() + 1);
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($fileVersion);
$em->flush();
```

Is there way to execute something like this in doctrine:

```
UPDATE file SET downloadCounter = downloadCounter + 1 WHERE id = 1
```

**EDIT:**

The problem in the doctrine example above is that between loading and flush is time where others could download the file and so the counter is not correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also do the following in an entity repository:

```
return $this
    ->createQueryBuilder('f')
    ->update($this->getEntityName(), 'f')
    ->set('f.downloadCounter', $file->getDownloadCounter() + 1)
    ->where('f.id = :id')->setParameter('id', $file->getId())
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();
```

Or using DQL:

```
 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
 $query = $em->createQuery(
     'UPDATE YourBundle:File f
      SET f.downloadCounter = :downloadCounter'
 )->setParameter('downloadCounter', $file->getDownloadCounter() + 1);
```

Or through a simplified DQL:

```
 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
 $query = $em->createQuery(
     'UPDATE YourBundle:File f
      SET f.downloadCounter = f.downloadCounter + 1'
 );
```

The drawback with these solutions: if your entity was already loaded it will have the previous count and not the incremented count.

The way you did is perfectly fine but a better way is to add an increment method to your entity.

Follow-up from Radu C comment below: **the simplified DQL is the only solution that guarantees proper count**.

The query increments based on the value in the database and locks the table guaranteeing queries to be executed in a sequence.

Whereas the other queries use the value in PHP runtime which may be an outdated value: some other request may have already incremented the value in the database therefore incrementing based on value in PHP memory will override increment made by other requests.

Comment: Thank you, your DQL helped me. instead of using `:downloadCounter` I did use `f.downloadCounter + 1` and added a where for file Id

Comment: I've added it as an example - glad my answer was helpful

Comment: thats not an answer, question is how to make incremental query, not how to summ value with +1

Comment: it does answer the question, his question can be renamed as "how to write this query in doctrine". I provided three different ways of writing the query. If there is fourth one then create a new answer.

Comment: This answer has a race condition (read-modify-write cycle) in the query builder and the DQL after it (User1 and User2 both download, so they read a counter of 1 and save a counter of 2 - you've lost a download). The "simplified" DQL does it properly - it tells the server to do the addition and lock the column from other writers.

Answer (score 2):

Safest way to do this is using Doctrine DBAL and call raw SQL that way you remove the chance of race condition and make the change atomic. Other option is to make the field versioned and use [optimistic locking](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html#optimistic-locking) or pessimistic DB-level locking.

Comment: Thomas Potaire answer is save as it is the same as the raw query. So no race condition there, but if you are editing some other fields also and don't want to create to have multiple queries the optimistic locking looks good!

Answer (score -4):

You could simply add an increment method to your model.

```
class File {
    public function increaseDownloadCounter()
    {
        $this->downloadCounter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does not execute as:

    UPDATE file SET downloadCounter = downloadCounter + 1 WHERE id = 1

Comment: Using this adds a race condition (read-modify-write cycle): User1 and User2 both download, so they read a counter of 1 and save a counter of 2 - you've lost a download.

Answer (score -4):

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$entity = $em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:EntityName')->find($entityId);
$valueToIncrement = $entity->getMyField(); // where MyField is the DB field to increment
$entity->setMyField(++$valueToIncrement);

$em->persist($entity);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: This approach will fail when there will be two less simultaneous requests - increment will be done only once.

Comment: Prone for race conditions.